# Append new lines to cronjob's output log

Tags: cron, cpanel

Right now I append my php script's output to a logfile. Unfortunately it writes everything in one line. How do I need to change my cron command to append every execution log in a new line?

My current cronjob looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/forum/cron.php >> /home/username/cron.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved by adding `echo ""` as below:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/forum/cron.php >> /home/username/cron.log 2>&1; echo "" >> /home/username/cron.log
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this post is old however I do not believe the approach above was the best solution.

The solution above will add a new line everytime the cronjob is run.

Now this is fine if after everytime the cronjob runs there is output.

However, if there is no output then `echo "" >> /home/username/cron.log` will print a new line into the cron.log.

I'd suggest adding `"\n"` to the php file where the output echoed. Then remove the `echo "" >> /home/username/cron.log` from the cronjob.

Eg:

```
echo "The cron job completed Successfully\n";
```

Comment: This option is much cleaner and using `echo ""` and allows you to control the result at the origin without modifying the handler.